# How to translate HTML 5 video with angular-translate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, video, angular-translate

I'm using the Angular JS extension [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) for language changing in my Cordova hybrid app with Mobile Angular UI.

**The problem:**

I found that I can't play the videos. And the video control bar is disabled. I looked in the source with Chrome's "Element Inspector" and saw that the file is there in `<source>`. I tried to copy the fully address and paste in the browser address bar and hit enter and the video started to play there in the browser window. So I know that the source address is the right one.

I realized that it could be a translate problem since I get the filename with translate code. And that is loading after the page is loaded. Then I tried to add [translate-compile](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive#using-translate-directive_post-compiling) attribute to the element. Didn't worked.

**So. What to do?**

Here is the code:

```
<video controls poster="img/video-posters/{{'view-vid-img' | translate}}"><source src="img/videos/{{'view-vid-nme' | translate}}" type="video/mp4">Video not supported</video>
```

**Edit:**

Here is a demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZZPJL1ReOC0ZOz4VI4kU?p=preview

Comment: An i18n/l10n system like angular-translate is really the wrong tool to use for this. You possibly want an `ng-switch` instead.

Comment: What... why? And if I don't have time to change the tool right now. Is there any way to solve the problem with angular-translate anyway?

Comment: @deceze I'm glad you answered! Could you please describe more how to do that? Or show by an example? Would be useful :)